# I'm getting a typed character every second or so on the console in Server 17.10

Tags: server, virtual-console

I tried to install Server 17.10 on my machine. As soon as the login prompt appeared, I started getting a character typed approximately once a second, even with no keyboard attached to the server. Each character displayed as "`^@`".

These characters do not appear in 16.04, but do appear in recovery mode on 17.10 and (if I remember correctly) in the 17.10 installer. They also don't appear in SSH sessions.

What could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this special character typed every second in different tty (ubuntu 17.10 desktop version)

I solved the problem by **installing a newer version of the Kernel (4.15)**.

Sources:

- [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1720219)
- [Kernel build 4.15](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/)
- [Install Kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds)